# Qt Creator Platformer Game - Can't make it work (Beginner with QGraphics)

Tags: c++, qt

i'm making a little game just for pratice. I basically want to make my character (a red triangle) move left and right, jump, etc.

The program is still very small at this state, And I wanna know 'how' I should do such things.

I've created a `Player Class(QObject, QGraphicsPolygonItem)` and a `Game Class(QGraphicsView)`. It worked at first when I gave the Player Class a method for KeyPressEvent, but I had a problem with the jump loop : I wanted to do a scene->update() inside my jump loop, But I couldn't because the scene is an attribute of my Game Class.

Then, I tried giving the Game Class the `PressKeyEvent method`, so it would move the Player * player attribute.

So basically, what I want is to be able to see the position of my rect update every iteration of my for loop. **Can I do that ?**

Hope this makes sense, and as always, thanks a lot guys !!

Player.h & Player.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <QGraphicsPolygonItem>
#include <QBrush>

class Player :
    public QObject, public QGraphicsPolygonItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Player();
    // Setters
    void setIsJumping(bool);
    // Getters
    bool getIsJumping();
    public slots:
private:
    bool isJumping;
};

#include "Player.h"


Player::Player()
{
    // ***************
    // Draw the player
    // ***************
    QVector<QPointF> gemPoints;
    gemPoints << QPointF(0, 2) << QPointF(1, 0) << QPointF(2, 2);
    // Size
    int SCALE_BY = 8;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < gemPoints.size(); i++)
    {
        gemPoints[i] *= SCALE_BY;
    }
    // Create the polygon
    QPolygonF gemModel(gemPoints);
    setPolygon(gemModel);
    setPos(400, 500);
    // Color
    QBrush brush;
    brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    brush.setColor(Qt::red);
    setBrush(brush);
    // Make player focusable
    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    this->setFocus();

}


void Player::setIsJumping(bool jump)
{
    if (jump == true)
    {
        isJumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}

bool Player::getIsJumping()
{
    return isJumping;
}
```

Game.h & Game.cpp

```
    #pragma once
    #include <QGraphicsView>
    #include <QGraphicsScene>
    #include <QKeyEvent>
    #include "Player.h"

    class Game :
        public QGraphicsView
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        // Constructors
        Game(QWidget* parent = NULL);
        // Methods
        void start();
        void jump();
        void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
        // Attributes
        QGraphicsScene* scene;
        Player* player;
    };

#include "Game.h"

Game::Game(QWidget* parent)
{
    // Set up the screen
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setFixedSize(1024, 768);

    // Set up the scene
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    setScene(scene);
}


void Game::start()
{
    scene->clear();
    player = new Player();
    scene->addItem(player);

}

void Game::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
    {
        player->setPos(x() - 3, y());
    }
    else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
    {
        player->setPos(x() + 3, y());
    }
    else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Space)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            player->setIsJumping(true);
            this->jump();
        }
    }
}

void Game::jump()
{
    if (player->getIsJumping() == true)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            this->player->setPos(x(), y() - 0.1);
            this->update();
        }
        player->setIsJumping(false);
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "plateforme.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "Game.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Game game;
    game.show();
    game.start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The problem is that I can't move the player correctly now, It moves only once and in a weird way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Btw, your `setIsJumping(bool jump)` should contain only `isJumping = jump;` That if-else is needless :)

Comment: I changed it, thanks. This was a bit dumb from me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you set the position for `player`, you should modify the coordinates of `player` and not of `this`. Therefore, whenever you want to move the `player`, use:

```
player->setPos(player->x() - 3, player->y());
                 ^                ^
```

and the same for jumping in your loop:

```
player->setPos(player->x(), player->y() - 0.1);
                  ^           ^
```

When you use `setPos(x()-3, y())`, it sets the player position to position of your `QGraphicsView`, that is why it disappears from the view. Good luck with your game!

Comment: Wow, thanks mate, I don't know why I didn't think about it earlier ! :)

Also, for the jumping part, I'm not sure how to implement it. Should I set a state isJumping when 'spacebar' is pressed for exemple, then call the jump method somwhere? I'm not sure where I should to call it.

Comment: You are welcome. Keep in mind: the best way to thank on Stackoverflow if someone's answer had helped you is to accept that answer ;) For the jump part: it is a subjective question, and there are always several ways to implement your design. If you are beginner in object-oriented design, it is only with trial and error you will gain more knowledge and good practices of how to design your software. Some questions to ask for yourself for that jump part: do you really need that `bool` variable? Do you have to implement jump as a loop? For every decision to make, I'd recommend KISS principle.

Comment: Well I managed to make the triangle go up, but If I wanna do it in a smooth way I though doing a for loop that moves the triangle and update the scene every iteration would make sense. Does it ? :p 

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, I see now what you mean. However, I do not think using loop is the appropriate solution to make the jump smooth. I could be wrong, but `QTimer` is probably what you need instead of the loop. The loop of 100 or even 1K or even 100K iterations - will not be enough to create that smooth movement you want, especially on fast modern machines.

Comment: Ok, I've red a bit about QTimer usage to make a proper Game Loop. I think i'm gonna try that. I wanna make a simplistic game, yet that has nice controls, like acceleration on movement, gravity and such, so I'm keeping it simple with a red triangle and maybe lines to represent the floor and meshes.

Comment: Is there anything such as a 'main loop' for QT ?

Comment: If you want to modify how `paint`, or `update` are done for the `QGraphicsView`, you could look for the [full list of its methods](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview-members.html) and figure out which you want to re-define and modify with your changes, for example [`paintEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent). That will allow you to modify behavior of the "main loop" on every update.

Comment: There are many ways to do the "main loop" in Qt and it depends a bit of the used graphics stack. For example in my QML/OpenGL game there's just a callback that is being called at 60 fps. If that's not the case, then just use QTimer. It's also possible to write a "traditional" while-loop if you handle all the events manually with QApplication::processEvents(), but I don't recommend that.